# iOS App Submission : remove iPad support

Tags: iphone, ipad

I have an iPhone App ( no native support of iPad layout ) launched in App Store for a year. My client wishes to remove the App from iPad's App Store.

I know it requires an update of the App, but how do I change my plist to reflect the changes?

Do Apple allows such changes? As I tried before, if I add hardware capabilities requirements, it will not pass the App Approval process.

**UPDATE**: more precisely, my client wants to remove support of those devices that without Messages (SMS) feature

**UPDATE**: requires support of iOS 4.3+ ( planned to support iPhone 3GS, iPhone 4/4S, iPhone 5 only )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final answer is:

Once you added iPad support in App submission, there is no way to remove it.

You have to block the access in iPad during App launch by checking `UIDevice.currentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad`

Comment: Will this work with the submission process? I mean will Apple approve this?

Comment: This is okay as long as you give user an explanation by an alert (or something similar)

Comment: It doesent work. I created a screen which said ipad version coming soon and that was the only screen which showed if the device was an ipad. But the app was rejected with the following reason: "Your app appears to be a pre-release, test, or trial version with a limited feature set. Apps that are created for demonstration or trial purposes are not appropriate for the App Store."

Comment: @PranavGupta never mention "coming soon". Apple will reject this.

Answer (score 0):

Every iPad supports Messages with iOS5, even first-gen. Every iPhone since 3GS does too.

Comment: I should state my requirements more clearly. I am now supporting iOS 4.3.5+, therefore, I have to cater iOS4 iPad's needs.

Comment: Oh, now I see your problem - you want to restring the app from launching on iPad in iPhone mode. You can't.

Comment: that's a sad answer. In other words, I have to decide which device I can support at the very beginning?

Comment: No, you don't understand. Every iPhone app CAN be launched on iPad, even if it doesn't have iPad support - it will be lauched in iPhone mode (small window in the center of iPad screen), you can't restrict that behaviour. So if your app doesn't have iPad UI support, you don't have to do anything except for making checks in your code if the device is capable of, for example, sending SMS.

Comment: understand your point, therefore I should change the Device Capabilities to require SMS to filter out iPad. But changing this requires submit a new app instead of an update, right?

Comment: last time I try to add new `UIDeviceCapabilities`, Apple rejected my app.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do it is to add some **Required Device capabilities** which iPad doesn't have. e.g., If you add **telephony** or **sms** to the **Required Device capabilities**, apple will automatically make the app available only for iPhone.

For more device capabilities, refer to https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

I hope it helps.

Comment: Did you try this? If you change Required Device capabilities, app will be rejected.

Comment: I haven't tried it but if the app actually includes a way to call/text someone, then I don't think they will reject the app.
And if rejection comes up only when there is no way in the app to call/text, then one can include some basic support call link etc.

Comment: Its confirmed now. My app is in the app store with this capability turned on but as I said you app should have call/SMS functionality somewhere.

Comment: Hi All, we are also facing the same issue, but with the latest update(10.3.3) by adding telephony key in Required Device capabilities won't stop installing in iPad, would appreciate if some one suggests alternative solution to restrict installing in iPad.

Comment: @NikhilJindal i've try the same i.e added the Required Device capabilities in my info.plist for the updated version of my app. But When i add the my latest build to application loader it does not accept the build.

Answer (score -2):

You must resubmit the application.
If you want remove iPad support from your app, follow this simple step:

1. Open Xcode
2. Click on your project name (on your left sidebar)
3. Click on target
4. Set iPhone as Devices

Honestly, a few years ago, I removed iPad support from my app and Apple has approved my changes.

Comment: As I stated in question, my app is already an iPhone App. It just, by default, can be shown in iPad.

Comment: Ah, maybe you mean 2x display on the iPad? You can't.

Comment: @Daniele: iphone application can be installed on iPad. The OP wants to prevent the installation of his iPhone app to iPad.

Answer (score -3):

just change your target .set it to iphone device

or
you can remove ipad support like this:

```
-(BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
     if (UIDevice.currentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
          return NO;


     return YES;
}
```

Comment: the App will still be available in iPad's App Store.