# Cordova 3.6.0: add only iphone support, no ipad at all

Tags: ios, iphone, cordova

when i create a new cordova project using the cordova cli, it creates a clean project presetting the target device to iphone, but still adding ipad resources.

I can also install the app on iPad, even if i select iPhone on the Device select box.

I compared the cordova project with a new project i created in xCode6 selecting iPhone. I see differences, for example in cordova i can still see "Supported interfaces orientations (iPad)" and also the icons and splash screens for iPad. But in my new default xCode6 project, i can only see iphone related stuff.

How can i make cordova created ONLY for iPhone, no ipad files at all?

**UPDATE:** The reason is NOT to disable iPad support, i know it has to run fine on iPads compatible mode, but i have scaling issues, because the project seems to have iPads related resources and settings i dont see because its set to iPhone only. I had to switch to iPad and untick the unwanted orientations because on iPad it was allowing landscape even if i build for iPhone only. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

When you launch the app, just launch it for iPhone alone if you don't want to support iPads.

Go through this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14373578/ios-app-submission-remove-ipad-support).

Here's the final accepted answer there:

> The final answer is:
>
> Once you added iPad support in App submission, there is no way to
>   remove it.
>
> You have to block the access in iPad during App launch by checking

```
UIDevice.currentDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad
```

Other then that every iPhone app will always launch on iPad even without support but will open in an smaller window.

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand. The problem is long before i launch the app, its about creating the xCode project with the "cordova create" call OR find some way to remove all the ipad resources and stuff from plist/pbx so the project works only for iPhone. Isn't that possible?

Comment: edited the answer, with that you should be able to display a msg saying "Not for iPad!" or so.